# Ionic 2 Page Change Subscription

Tags: ionic2

How can I subscribe to page changes in Ionic 2? I'd just like to log page names/titles globally. Is there an event I can subscribe to?

Comment: you could use [events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) for something like this..

Comment: I would like to do this globally so I don't have to touch every file

Comment: You should listen to the app components root navcontrollers's events.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby if you can turn that into an answer with some sample code, I would gladly accept it

Answer (score 2):

create a service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RouteNamesService{
    constructor(){
    }
  public name = new Subject();

  setRouteName(name){
      this.name.next(name);
  }
}
```

in app.component.ts
subscribe to

```
 this.routeNamesService.name.subscribe(name => this.routeName = name);
```

when you enter in to a component then fire

```
this.routeNamesService.setRouteName("Settings");
```

(or)  in app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.nav.viewDidEnter.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);

    });

  }
```

in data you can get component name